# Adding dataframe values as parameters to sql query

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am trying to iterate through a dataframe and fetching values from indivdidual column to use as my parameters in sql query.

```
for index,frame in df1.iterrows():

      sql = "select * from issuers where column_1 = %s;"
      cur.execute(sql, frame['column_1'])
      row = cur.fetchone()
      id = row[0]
      print id
```

But I am getting the following error

> "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

How can I solve this? In case I need to add multiple parameters, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
cur.execute(sql, frame['column_1'])
```

Try this:

```
cur.execute(sql, [frame['column_1']])
```

The second parameter of `execute` is a list containing all values to be inseted into `sql`.

In order to insert multiple values use something as follows:

```
sql = "select * from issuers where column_1 = %s and column_2 = %s;"
cur.execute(sql, ["val1", "val2"])
```

For more information please refere to the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

**EDIT**

Here an example for `INSERT INTO` in SQL.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cur.execute(sql, ["John", "Doe"])
```

Comment: @themaster I have added an example in my answer above. I hope that helps